# Warning message after updating

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, error-handling

I have Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon edition and after updating using the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I got this warning message:

```
...
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gir1.2-rb-3.0 rhythmbox rhythmbox-data
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

What does it mean that the packages have been kept back?

and, moreover, why after upgrading the terminal does not upgrade 3 packages?

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means that, for some reason, `apt-get upgrade` determined that it should leave those three packages alone. Generally speaking that's because upgrading them would break something else. You can try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` instead to see what `apt-get` does if you let it remove packages as well. You'll always be asked to confirm before a package is removed...

In this specific case you could also get more information by running `sudo apt-get install rhythmbox`; that will ask `apt-get` to upgrade `rhythmbox` to the latest version and will show what's preventing that, if anything.